# JWT Token BouncyCastle exception

Tags: docusignapi

I developed a program to use the DocuSign API but I have a problem when I try to receive a JWT Token. I get the following exception:

```sh
System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'BouncyCastle.Crypto, Version=1.8.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0e99375e54769942' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'
```

Here is the code I am testing.

```
public void GetToken()
{
    OAuth.OAuthToken authToken = ApiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(ClientID, ImpersonatedUserGuid, 
       AuthServer, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PrivateKey), 1);

    AccessToken = authToken.access_token;

    if (Account == null)
       Account = GetAccountInfo(authToken);

    Console.WriteLine(authToken);
}
```

Comment: how did you get the DocuSign.eSign.dll library? did you use nuget package manager? it has some dependent dlls that have to be added as well.

Comment: Yes i used the nuget package manager. I test a new installation on a clean projet and i don't get this error. So is it possible to uninstall all packages from the nuget manager and make a new install properly ?

Comment: yes, let me answer below

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you have all the dependent DLLs.
Nuget manager many not remove them when you remove a package in some cases because they're used by other things as well as when you upgrade you may not get new ones.
If you can, remove all nuget packages and re-add them again.
If that's too much, you would have to add the ones that are missing manually. 
Note also that a solution has multiple projects and the VS would allow you to pick which project for which nuget package.
You can always just manually edit the .csproj file as well to add the missing reference, if the package is there but just not being linked.